# Встроенные данные в форме

Tags: php, html

Приветствую! 
На сайте имеется 5 разных форм. 
Скрипт сохраняет в переменную данные из полей (имя, почта, телефон) и отправляет их на мою почту. Нужно сделать так, что бы по-мимо всей информации, что будут вводить пользователи сайта, в содержании письма было указанно название формы, с которой было отправлено сообщение.
Как можно это реализовать?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Обратная связь</title>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="4; URL=http://"> 
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$sendto   = "@gmail.com"; 
$username = $_POST['name'];  
$usertel = $_POST['telephone']; 
$usermail = $_POST['email']; 
$usluga = $_POST['usl'];

// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";

$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
 echo "<center><img src='images/spasibo.png'></center>";
} else {
 echo "<center><img src='images/ne-otpravleno.png'></center>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="name form">` https://webref.ru/html/input/type

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="название_формы">
    // не видно для пользователя
    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="название_формы" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

К предыдущему ответу добавлю, что в серверном обработчике надо добавить

```html
// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";

// Добавить эту строку
$msg .= "<p><strong>Форма:</strong> ".$_REQUEST['form-name']."</p>\r\n";

$msg .= "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Не вижу почему это проблема? Достаточно дописать в формируемое сообщение, в  блок кода с конкатенацией переменной $msg дополнение типа "Форма заказа одежды" или "Форма заказа обуви" или что там вам нужно. К примеру:

```
$msg .= "<p>Отправлено формой заказа раздела <strong>Одежда</strong></p>\r\n";
```

А что б было ещё удобней, можно прямо в теме письма указывать с какой формы пришло сообщение. Тогда нужно менять строку с переменной $subject. К примеру:

```
$subject  = "Новое сообщение, форма раздела Фурнитура";
```